# Parameters of $ y_i = \beta_0^2 + \beta_0 \beta_1 x_i$

Tags: estimation, nonlinear-regression, estimators

I have this model, nonlinear in the parameters

$
y = \beta_0^2 + \beta_0  \beta_1 x_i
$

exist a known estimation of parameters ?

Comment: Is there any problem rewriting your model in terms of $\alpha_0=\beta_0^2$ and $\alpha_1 = \beta_0 \beta_1$, which *is* linear?

Comment: He needs to use a function like `nls ` in stats package to estimate.

Comment: @whuber I don't know, but $\alpha_1$ depend of $\sqrt{\alpha_0}$, this can cause some problem ? or, can cause a problem in the estimation of confidence interval ?

Comment: @stat I search a solution like get with ordinary least squares (OLS)

Comment: I mean something like [this](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/nls.html). But you need some good starting points.

Comment: @stat yes, I understand you suggestion about `nls`, but this use numerical methods and (like you say) need stating points. I search an analytical expression, for this I mentioned OLS.

Comment: @Stat Given whuber's comment (effectively a brief answer), if you know that $\beta_0\geq0$ (or even $\beta_0\leq0$), starting points for nonlinear least squares are obvious ... but they'll also be the ending points, since the SSE is already at a minimum! If the OP doesn't know which sign the first parameter has, the nonlinear model is indeterminate, since you can flip the signs of both parameters without changing the fit.

Comment: @Glen_b: he can try different starting points, then look at performance of the fitted models to pick up his starting points. I am not sure about flipping the the signs. Maybe you are right. Anyhow .... he can pick up two models ;)

Comment: @Stat what would be the point of different starting points? You can identify all reasonable (final) solutions instantly from running two OLS models (one with $\beta_0>0$ and one with it $<0$ -- and the second of those can be computed from the first, in any case). No nls model of the form suggested can do any better. To see that, choose any set of values for the $\beta$ parameters and there's an obvious OLS model with the same fit.